# How to put strings in Pydev refactoring dialog from eclipse plugin?

Tags: java, python, eclipse, plugins, pydev

I'm trying to call the pydev refactoring dialog and put the new/old string for refactoring and the file, but did not find in the tests of pydev source.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at `com.python.pydev.refactoring.refactorer.refactorings.renamelocal.RefactoringLocalTestBase.applyRenameRefactoring(RefactoringRequest, boolean)` -- used from `com.python.pydev.refactoring.refactorer.refactorings.renamelocal.RenameBuiltinTest.testRename3()` (you can try to do a debug session there to understand more about how it works).

Comment: when running the test, it is supposed to show a dialog? just tried to debug, putting a breaking point in first line of testRename3, looked all the way to applyRenameRefactoring, but don't get the dialog at all, the test all passed, but got a lot of 'java.lang.RuntimeException: Not implemented'

Comment: Humm, no, it doesn't really open the dialog... sorry I thought you just wanted to make a rename... can you give more details on why you need the dialog to be opened?

Comment: I need to let the user do the confirm action and a way to show what will be renamed (preview), and this is exactly what the dialog have

Comment: Or is there anoter way to achieve the same goal without opening the dialog with the strings inside it?